# Java.Eclipse gives error on declaring a variable with type outside the method with parameters

Tags: java, eclipse

The following is my code and i am using Eclipse IDE.

So i have created two classes from which one of them is called `Mainclass` and the other one is called `Testclass`.

The following code works fine but if i declare the variables which are `i` and `j` of type integer outside the calculate method with type int or integer and write the variable names only inside the calculate method's parenthesis then it shows error.I want to know why is this happening and below my original code is the changed code as described by me above which shows absurd errors.

[Original code works fine]

```
package calculation;

public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testclass obj=new Testclass();
        System.out.println(obj.calculate(10,20));
    }
}


public class Testclass {
    int a;
    public int calculate(int i, int j) {
        a=i+j;  
        return a;
    }      
}
```

[/Original code works fine]

[This code does not works fine]

```
package calculation;

public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testclass obj=new Testclass();
        System.out.println(obj.calculate(10,20));
    }

}



 public class Testclass {
     int a;
     int i;
     int j;
     public int calculate(i,j) {
          a=i+j;    
          return a;
     }      
 }
```

[/This code does not works fine]

Why we must declare the variable with its' type inside the method's parenthesis but not outside it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of declaring parameters in Java is

```
public int calculate(int i,int j){}
```

providing the data type of the parameters passed to the methods

You can also do this

```
public class Testclass {
    int a;
    int i;
    int j;
    public int calculate(int i, int j) {
        a=i+j;
        return a;
    }      
}
```

This will compile fine. But remember parameters passed `i & j`, i.e. local variables in the method `calculate` have no relation with the instance variables `i & j`.

Comment: because it's the java syntax, if you don't follow the syntax rules, compiler will throw error.

Comment: Fahad: because those are local variables, declared locally, and are not related (as far as the compiler is concerned) to your instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Testclass {
          int a;
          int i;
          int j;
          public int calculate(i,j) {
          a=i+j;    
          return a;
          }      
          }
```

In your method parameters, you are declaring local variables, they are not the same as the instance variables i and j.

This meaning: you must declare them with a type. At this point, the compiler does not know what those local i and j are, so he doesn't know what to do with them.

```
public class Testclass {
          int a;
          int i;
          int j;
          public int calculate(int i, int j) {
          a=i+j;    
          return a;
          }      
          }
```

This will solve your issue, but remember: the i and j used in the method, are the local variables, not the instance members.

Answer (score 1):

This is a requirement of Java programming that while defining a method you need to specify type of the parameters which that method has. Parameters correspond to the data type of the primitive or class / interface type which the method is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a method's signature

```
public int calculate(int i, int j)
```

So whenever you declare a method, you have to define the data type of the variables that your method takes as arguments.

**UPDATE :**

When you say already defined the variables like

```
class Testclass
{
    int a;
    int i;  //this is an instance variable
    int j;  //this is an instance variable

    public int calculate(i, j)  // you have to define the type here, method signature does not know what your instance variables are
    {
        a = i + j;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i already defined the type of variables above in my not working code.

Comment: No, you didn't. read the other replies. You are hiding your class/instance variables with local variables. For the compiler, they are not related.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code:

- you forgot to declare type of parameters of method `calculate`. When you pass an argument to a method, you need to specify its type. Java require all variables to have a declared type.
- every class have to stay in its file, except inner classes.
- if you want to create an instance of TestClass from a static method, you have to declare TestClass as static. In this way, it doesn't need to reference an instance of `MainClass`.

If you want to declare both classes in the same file (`MainClass.java`):

```
package calculation;

public class Mainclass {

public static class TestClass {
    int a;

    public int calculate(int i, int j) {
        a = i + j;
        return a;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass obj = new TestClass();
    System.out.println(obj.calculate(10, 20));

}


}
```